# Django Adding a delete action to a template

Tags: python, django

I have a dashboard template where users can upload files and it displays them.  I want to add a delete action to this.  I have a few ideas but need some help ironing them out.

I am also not sure where I should be using FileStorage or a custom FileStorage backend.  Would using these make it easier/simpler for managing files (deleting them, listing them, etc.) than the solution I have now?

First my code...

The view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/dashboard-login/')
def dashboard(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_client = request.user.client

    files = ClientUpload.objects.filter(client=current_client)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            dz_files = request.FILES.getlist('file_upload')
            for f in dz_files:
                new_file = ClientUpload(client=current_client, file_upload=f)
                new_file.save() 
                logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
                logger.info("File uploaded from " + current_client.company)
        else:
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.warning("Upload Failed")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    data = {'form': form, 'client': current_client, 'files': files}
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my dashboard view.  If the request is POST then I process the form.

And here is my model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ClientUpload(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Client Uploads")
        verbose_name = _("Client Upload")
```

The ideas I had are these:

First, could I use the else for when it is not a POST method and try processing the delete action there?  What I am trying to delete is the ClientUpload model which represents the file.  Does the delete model action use POST?  I would assume it does, so how could I tell whether they are submitting the form or deleting something?

Which brings me to my second idea?

Second, could I just make a second view?  Called something like dashboard_delete.  And process it that way just making sure I return the same template and context as my normal dashboard view?  I could use a CBV with DeleteView, but I'm not so sure, I still have the same questions as the first idea, as well as will it work with this approach?  Having two views that render the same template, but delete will only be called when you press the delete button which will be a link that routes to this view?  Are there any problems here?

Third, should I use a class based view for this?  By overriding dispatch and post?  Are there any other methods I can override for the delete?  I would rather not do this one.

Basically which would work the best of these 3 solutions?  Is there a better solution for this?  I essentially have them log in, but they are not staff and cannot access the admin interface.  I know they should be able to delete these files as they uploaded them, but do I need another permission for this?  Is there a way I can customize this delete action via overriding or anything?

Any help and examples would be a tremendous benefit for me, I've been stuck for a bit on this and could use any help.

I just really need help finding the best approach, which seems to be the second solution, I'm just not sure how to implement it exactly and whether I can customize the things I mentioned like the delete method (can I send the deleted files to a hidden recycle bin(just another folder) so that only the admin can see them?).  Will it work the way I intend?

Any information would help a lot as my testing always seems to have issues.  Will keep posting updates as I keep testing, but any input would help a lot, as I said I've been stuck a bit.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Template for file list:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load sasite_filters %}

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Filename{% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Size (Bytes){% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Upload Time{% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Actions{% endblocktrans %}</th>
</tr>
{% for file in files %}
    {% with uploaded_file=file.file_upload %}  
 <tr>
    <th><a href='{{ uploaded_file.url }}'>{{ uploaded_file.name|pathend}}</a></th>
    <th>{{ uploaded_file.size }}</th>
    <th>{{ file.created_at }}</th>
    <th>Delete, Downloads, etc.</th>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could actually be pretty simple, write another view method to handle the delete event. Give each entry in the template a button, which should point to the url that links to your deletion view method. In the view you can do whatever you like to delete the model object, then redirect to your dashboard view.

Rough example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def delete(request, upload_id):
    p = ClientUpload.objects.get(pk=upload_id)
    p.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('your-dashboard-url')
```

Comment: So as long as I render the same template and include necessary context data I'll be fine?  Is the delete a POST?

Comment: See my edit for an example. Delete is just a separate view method.

Comment: @shenk put that in a `if request.method == 'POST'`

Comment: @gocht No it's not a `POST` request, it's a `GET`. That's why I didn't specify anything in the method.

Comment: Hey dumb question, for pk=upload_id How would I pass that argument in the template?  I would call it with `{% url 'dashboard-delete' arg1 %} ? What do I pass as arg1 based on my  model?  Since I want to make sure I'm deleting the correct one.

Comment: Take a look here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut. Since I don't know what you use as a primary key, `pk` is a safe bet. From your comment, sounds like you are using default primary key, so the `arg1` is the id of the object.

Comment: Right i'm using the default so it is pk, but when I pass arg1, what would I pass?  Would it be file.id?  In my edit you can see my template code.  I'm assuming it would be file.id or uploaded_file.id but is there a better way to access the id in a template?

Comment: Yes, it's `file.id`. What you will pass as `arg1` will become `upload_id` variable name in the view method.

Comment: Thought so thanks.  I have one more newb question.  I'm having some trouble with my urls.py file for this delete action.  What regex do I use?  Do I want to include the pk in it? so dashboard/delete/<pk>/ or whatever? And  since it will render the dashboard.html template it doesn't matter the url is different?  I basically, I'm not sure what to set the url entry to.

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow is not an interactive exercise place. For these basic django knowledge you should refer to django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/. But basically you can do `url(r'^delete/(?P<upload_id>\d+)$', views.delete, name='delete')`.

Comment: Thank you! I had the regex somewhere in an old project, but I was having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use GenericViews if you wanted: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView

It's very simple. For example:

**views.py:**

```
class ClientUploadDelete(DeleteView):
    model = ClientUpload
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    template_name = 'client_upload_delete.html'
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ClientUploadDelete.as_view(), name="delete_client_upload"),
```

**html:**

```
<button type="button">
    <a href="{% url 'client_upload_delete' %}">Delete</a>
</button>
```

That's it. The user will be prompted with a screen that verifies if they want to delete the object. If they say yes, it will redirect them to `dashboard.html` in the example above.

**EDIT:**

*`client_upload_delete.html`*

```
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
    {% if request.user == object.user %}
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this object?</p>
        # Put your object here (image, text item, etc.)
        <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location='{% url 'dashboard' %}'"/>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        <h4>You're not allowed to be here.</h4>
        <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Fun twist: Override `get` to return `HttpResponse(status=405)` (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) and trigger the delete by submitting a POST to the View instead of GET for insta-deletion (useful with, say, [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)).

Comment: Where does the verification screen come from?

Comment: Also client_upload_delete.html doesn't actually exist, it's just the dashboard with a button that links to the delete url which routes to the delete view, but the delete view returns the dashboard template as well.  There is no additional template for deletions.

Comment: @shenk You need to create `client_upload_delete.html` (or whatever you want to name it). I'll post an example template as an edit to my answer.

Comment: @jape But my delete action is on the same template as dashboard.html  It's just a delete action, it doesn't need a template.  Right?  I just have it render dashboard.html after deleting.